# Sapper: How to import CSS from node_modules?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I am trying to do this (in sapper):

```
<style global>
@import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css';
</style>
```

But getting 404's on the frontend.

Also seeing 404s from a module in there that is importing CSS.

Comment: Can you show your rollup config?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can easily import CSS directly from your node_modules folder using the webpack and the CSS Loader. This is superior to just copy-and-pasting the CSS code because it ensures that the CSS style you are using for your website will always be in sync with your version of the library

By Using (~) you can import the CSS from the Node Modules:-

@import "~package/css-stylesheet";

div {
  background-image: url("~package/image.jpeg");
}
```